# how to backup and restore database(oracle 9i ) using sql developer

Tags: database, oracle, backup

Could you please let me know is there any way to backup and restore Oracle 9i database through Sql Developer.

I've been asked to do it though I am a developer and don't have DBA rights.

Thanks in advance,
Savitha

Comment: [This](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25107/how-to-take-oracle-backup-and-restore)  question on dba.stackexchange answers your question:

Comment: Oracle backup is painful compared to SQL Server. Oracle permissions can be set up in such a way as you don't have the rights to backup and restore the full database. So you think you have a backup until you try to restore it and then find out you can't restore part of it. As SQL Server gains more market share Oracle will eventually have to make a proper backup.

Answer (score 6):

No. Not really. You should use RMAN to do backup and recovery.

Check out the [Backup and Recovery roadmap](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a97202/toc.htm) for where you should learn about 9i backup.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracles SQL Developer click in the menue bar on `Extras-> Database Copy.` Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI to use for backup and recovery is Oracle Enterprise Manager Grid- or Datbase console.
To check where OEM is running log on to the database server. Set your environment to the database and run

```
#> emctl status dbconsole
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do backup & recovery thru sql developer. You should use RMAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Export Tables and Import Tables actions from the Tools menu item as an alternative to backup and restore, if all you need is to keep a copy of just the data.